# Generic type inference with a derived type

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

class `Property` is `abstract`

I have the following method:

```
private IPortionOfPropertyInfoAddEditView<T> getPropertyEditPortion<T>(T property) where T : Property { /*details unimportant*/ }

Property P = PropertyFactoryMethod.GetSomePropertyInstance();

var PropertyInfoPortion = getPropertyEditPortion(P);
```

When I call the method this way, the type that's inferred is Property, and not the more derived `Well`, or `RealEstate`, presumably because the type inference is being done at compile time. I've worked around this by casting P to `dynamic`, like:

```
var PropertyInfoPortion = getPropertyEditPortion((dynamic)P);
```

which works fine.  I'm just wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I always try to show the least amount of code to get the point across so things don't get too cluttered.  Here's the full method:

```
    private IPortionOfPropertyInfoAddEditView<T> getPropertyEditPortion<T>(T property) where T : Property {
        return StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IPortionOfPropertyInfoAddEditView<T>>();         
    }
```

I have an instance of Property (which is abstract) and I was using type inference to get the true type to pass to my IoC, without having to resort to reflection (to put together the right generic type).  I was just wondering if there was a trick whereby this could be done without `dynamic` casting, but I guess not.  Thanks all.

**EDIT 2**

I'm trying to create a  `IPortionOfPropertyInfoAddEditView<T>`

My Property instance, P, is of the type that IPortionOfPropertyInfoAddEditView needs, but it's typed as Property, not the more derived type.  I would just love it if I could say:

```
StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IPortionOfPropertyInfoAddEditView<typeof(P)>>()
```

But that's obviously not allowed.  I figured type inference with a dynamic cast would be the next best thing, I just was wondering if anyone had a better way.  Sorry for not being clear from the start!

Comment: What's in the body of the method that makes it so important that the type-argument be the same as (presumably) the run-time type of the argument?

Comment: Interesting... I learned something today!  I think what you did is pretty elegant, Adam...  Like @Ani, I am also wondering what difference it makes...

Comment: @ani - The result of the method is based on the type argument - it *must* be the most derived type

Comment: @Adam: If you could provide a simple example of how the result is different, it might help us.

Comment: @Adam: But you haven't shown us the 'desirable' (non-dynamic) usage of the method. Without context, it's really hard to answer this question sensibly. One more question: Is the interface covariant?

Comment: The method essentially just calls my IoC to get an instance of IPortionOfProprtyEdit<T>.  I have an instance of my property (the T above), and I didn't want to use reflection to build a generic type to pass to IoC, so I used method type inference.

Comment: Ani - I was asking to *find out* if a desirable non-dynamic solution existed - I guess one doesn't :)  The interface is not covariant - if it were, would there be another option?

Comment: Full method shown - sorry for not posting enough info initially

Comment: @Adam: I meant show us desirable *usage*. For example, what sort of variable would you (ideally) want to assign the result of the method to, if the inferencing worked off the run-time type? `object`? `dynamic`?  A covariant conversion to `IPortionOfPropertyInfoAddEditView<LessSpecificType>`? A non-generic `IPortionOfPropertyInfoAddEditView`? It's really hard to find meaning in your comment "the result of the method is based on the type argument - it must be the most derived type".

Comment: @Adam: I just saw your edit. You are not using the argument anywhere! Could you explain why you are passing an argument in the first place? Is it a dummy to help the compiler infer types?

Comment: I use the generic parameter at the end of the only line in the method (you might have to scroll right - if you're on an iPhone you're out of luck :)).  The type I'm constructing, IPortionOfProperty<T> is itself generic.  I have an instance that represents the type that IPortionOfProperty will take.  Since you can't say (the equivalent of) new GenericType<typeof(P)> I used type inference instead.

Comment: Say latest edit - I should have included more info in the original question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do it with generics, as generics always operate on the static type of values. The fact that you worked around this by using a runtime mechanism (`dynamic`) is a good hint for this.

There are a number of good runtime solutions, but it depends on what exactly you want to do with `property` (i.e., which members you want to access, the visibility of said members, etc).

Comment: "using a runtime mechanism (dynamic) is a good hint for this" - yeah, I know.  I just wanted to be sure.  Thank you and +1

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to mind would be to make the implementation of `getPropertyEditPortion` a method of the `Property` class.

Then, you wouldn't need to care what the derived type of `P` is in this case, you simply invoke your method, and the correct implementation gets run.

If that's not really feasible, then using the `dynamic` keyword seems appropriate.

Comment: It's not feasible - that would set up bad dependencies, but good thought.  +1